# to get values from 2 columns using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

in the below code i want to search a data from coursemaster table .i am searching course code from coursemaster table and i want to search course name from coursemaster pls anyone help me.

coursemaster:

### coursecode | coursename

controller:coursemaster_site

```
function index1()
    {
        $data            = array();
        $keyword         = $this->input->post('keyword');
        if($keyword!=""){
            $data['results'] = $this->coursemaster_model->search($keyword);
        }
        $this->load->view('coursemaster_view', $data);

    }


  model:coursemaster_model

function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('course_code',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('coursemaster');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->like('course_code',$keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('course_name',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('coursemaster');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use or_like

```
$this->db->like('course_code',$keyword);
$this->db->or_like('course_name', $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [or_like](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
function search($keyword1,$keyword2){
        $this->db->like('course_code',$keyword1);
        $this->db->or_like('course_code',$keyword2);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('coursemaster');
        return $query->result();
    }
```